# string.replace not chaining in grunt and grunt-angular-templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am using grunt and ngtemplates to load my templates into the templatecache.

In the url function im trying to make the url a bit cleaner by stripping out '.html' etc, with the following code:

```
url: function(url) {
    grunt.log.writeln("in url: " + url);
    url = url.replace(/app\//i, '').replace(/\/templates/i, '').replace(/areas\//i, '').replace('.html', '');
    grunt.log.writeln("ret url: " + url);
    return url;
}
```

If I run the same logic in the node console it works fine. In grunt/ ngtemplates however, it only seems to run the first replace.

But when I split the replaces up, it works as expected.

```
url: function(url) { 
    grunt.log.writeln("in url: " + url);
    url = url.replace(/app\//i, '');
    url = url.replace(/\/templates/i, '');
    url = url.replace(/areas\//i, '');
    url = url.replace('.html', '');
    grunt.log.writeln("ret url: " + url);
    return url;
}
```

I know this way works, and I could do it in one replace using regex, but I'm at a loss to explain why the first way doesn't work.

**EDIT**

A test case is `app/common/templates/toolbar/toolbar.html`

Comment: what is your test string

Comment: Why you you not using just one regular expression?

Comment: No, both your codes are equivalent.

Comment: @epascarello My first attempt got me wondering why it wasn't working. So the question was really about why there's a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js should not be a problem, which version you are using.
[image]